# Expected behavior for repeated OAuth 2 access token request

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm implementing OAuth 2 for an application and I cannot find expected behavior in the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) when it comes to repeating a successful token request.

My questions are:

When a successful request is repeated

- should it return the same Bearer token as before?
- or should it return a new token and invalidate the previous?
- or should it return a new token which exists next to the other? So you authorize by both tokens.

I saw that the [twitter implementation](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth2/token) returns the same token but is this according to the specification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected behavior is that the Authorization Server returns a new access token. The Authorization Server may invalidate the previous access token based on the security policy that it maintains, there's no requirement for that. Access tokens should be short lived and a new access token should be requested only if the old one is expired or about to expire anyway. In addition to that: the format of the bearer token may be such (e.g. a self-contained JWT) that it cannot even be revoked.

Comment: Could you please share the source of your information? Mainly that "the expected behavior is that the Authorization Server returns a new access token."? Thanks!